# resolving per pixel collision issue

Tags: c++, collision-detection

In space invader, I'm doing bullet to barrier intersection using rect to rect, then I'm testing the first bullet's impact pixel, if it's green I blast a circle, if it's black, it continues travelling. now there is a situation that there is part of the barrier that won't be checked for intersection, as shown in the image, the first intersection test will fail, because the first pixel is black... 
[image]
How would I resolve that issue ?

Comment: can you explain the "intersection test will fail, because the first pixel is black" part. which intersection will fail ? your image doesn't demonstrate any intersection

Comment: I mean I first doing rect-rect intersection between the bullet and the barrier. Then I check if the pixel is green, then I blast the circle, otherwise, I skip the collision part. But in the case in the image, there were some green blocks and they are blasted, but the intersection is called, and the first pixel it sees is black, then the bullet will travel over the green part that is in the picture